# Ec2 instances are working fine but in CLB it is showing as Outofservice

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am not running any website or application in my ec2 instance.  I have just attached one EBS volume to my ec2 instance. When I tried to connect to the ec2 instance it was working fine and also another ec2 is also connecting to my ec2 without any error. But in **Classic Load Balancer** it is showing as `outofservice` .

I have checked security groups also, all those seem to be fine.

Healthcheck Port: 80
Healthcheck Path: /

Comment: IS apache or ngnix ecc running in EC2? You need to have port 80 listening for the load balancer to make the instance healthy.

Comment: I have port 80 in elb listeners. My ec2 is just like DFS server it have only ebs volume . There is no application like apache or ngnix running on it. Is that possible to make the ec2 as inserve in elb

Comment: In that case you can make tcp healthcheck with ping port 22(or any other service running).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no application or server listening on port 80, then the healthcheck from the **CLB** will fail and you should get an `OutOfService` status for the **EC2** instance.

The first step is to make sure your app is running and accepting HTTP requests. For other possible issues with failed health checks:
[Troubleshooting CLB connectivity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ts-elb-healthcheck.html)

Comment: My ec2 is just like DFS server it have only ebs volume . There is no application like apache or ngnix running on it. Is that possible to make the ec2 as inserve in elb